# How to determine data transmission rate from an eye diagram?

Tags: oscilloscope, digital-communications

I would like to know how to determine the data transmission rate from an eye diagram such as the one given below:

[image]

Would it be the reciprocal of the length of time from the start of the diagram to the end? In this case 3 micro seconds?

Comment: How is your sync and trigger for the scope? Can you zoom out and take a normal single pass capture too?

Comment: Symbol lenght appears to be 2µs, and there are three voltage levels.

Comment: It could also be MLT-3 Multi-Level Transmission Encoding (3-Levels). A tri-level encoding method where a change in the logic level represents a code bit “1” and the logic output remaining at the
same level represents a code bit “0”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observations:

- Symbol lenght appears to be 2µs, and there are three voltage levels.
- There is no transition from 1V to 2V in the diagram.

Hypothesis: There is a coding on top that pairs two symbols to encode 3 bits, and the eye diagram was recorded relative to the start of symbol pairs.

In this case, you get 3 bits per 4µs.